# The 'graphlib' utility is a mandatory dependency

Tags: vuejs2, jointjs

I am using joint js 3.1.1 version and graphlib 2.1.8 version.

I have a code in my app to check cyclic reference in graph. For that purpose I have written below code

```
graphlib.alg.findCycles(graph.toGraphLib())
```

This line gives following error

```
Uncaught Error: The the "graphlib" utility is a mandatory dependency.
    at Object.toGraphLib (joint.min.js?de6d:8)
    at child.He.toGraphLib (joint.min.js?de6d:8)
    at RestrictCyclicConnection (links.js?2d1e:46)
    at child.eval (businessobjectdesigner.vue?b25b:856)
    at triggerEvents (backbone.js?ab5c:338)
    at triggerApi (backbone.js?ab5c:322)
    at eventsApi (backbone.js?ab5c:110)
    at child.Events.trigger (backbone.js?ab5c:312)
    at child.notify (joint.min.js?de6d:8)
    at child._notifyConnectEvent (joint.min.js?de6d:8)
```

I have imported graphlib in my file also. But still getting following error.

I have imported graphlib as

```
import graphlib from 'graphlib'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try by passing graphlib as a part of the options object, as follows-

`graph.toGraphLib({graphlib: graphlib})`